# Cross or Inner Join two tables that have one non-unique column in common

Tags: sql, inner-join, cross-join

I have two tables; the first shows all (unique) persons. It contains a column showing the type of house each person would like to have. The second table shows all unique ads. Each row also contains the type of house in the ad. So `HouseType` is not unique in both tables.

I'd like to have a SQL statement that results in all possible combinations as long as `HouseType` is the same. I suspect I need some kind of cross join statement. Hope you can help.

Table 1:

```
PersonID    Name    HouseType
-------------------------------
P1          Jane    Appartment
P2          Jack    Mansion
P3          Jo      Appartment
P4          Jill    Studio
```

Table 2:

```
AdID    HouseType
-------------------
A1      Mansion
A2      Appartment
A3      Mansion
A4      Appartment
A5      Studio
A6      Studio
A7      Appartment
```

Desired output table from SQL statement:

```
AdID    HouseType   PersonID    Name
-------------------------------------
A1      Mansion     P2          Jack
A2      Appartment  P1          Jane
A2      Appartment  P3          Jo
A3      Mansion     P2          Jack
A4      Appartment  P1          Jane
A4      Appartment  P3          Jo
A5      Studio      P4          Jill
A6      Studio      P4          Jill
A7      Appartment  P1          Jane
A7      Appartment  P3          Jo
```

Comment: This is just a join -- all results in a 2nd table that match the value in the first table.  (All ads that match a house type.)

Comment: Please: Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Don't edit your post in a way that invalidates reasonable existing answer posts. If you have another (specific researched non-duplicate) question then ask it in another post. I rolled back your adding a new question here. [ask] [Help] Please show parts you are able to do. Explain about being stuck. Debug questions require a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

Cross JOIN will used only when you need to repeat all records of Table2 per every single record of table2 but in your case things are different.

You should use INNER JOIN

```
SELECT t2.AId, t2.HouseType, t1.PersonId, t1.Name
FROM Table1 t1
  Inner JOIN Table2  t2 ON t1.HouseType = t2.HouseType
```